# Azure Storage: use AzCopy.exe to copy a folder from blob storage to another storage account

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, azcopy

Using AzCopy.exe, I am able to copy over an entire container successfully. However, I cannot figure out how to copy over a blob where the name includes a folder structure.  I have tried the following:

```
.\AzCopy.exe /Source:https://sourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container /Dest:https://destaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container /SourceKey:sourceKey== /DestKey:destKey== /S /Pattern:CorruptZips/2013/6
```

While also changing the /Pattern: to things like:

- /Pattern:CorruptZips/2013/6/*
- /Pattern:CorruptZips/2013/6/.
- /Pattern:CorruptZips/2013/6/

And everything just says that there are zero records copied.  Can this be done or is it just for container/file copying?  Thank you.

Comment: The slashes in your blob name pattern are probably being interpreted as additional parameters.  Try putting quotes around the parameter value. /Pattern:"CorruptZips/2013/6/*".

Answer (score 3):

@naspinski, there is the other tool named `Azure Data Factory` which can help copying a folder from a blob storage account to another one. Please refer to the article [Move data to and from Azure Blob using Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-blob-connector/) to know it and follow the steps below to do.

1. Create a Data Factory on Azure [portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/?feature.relex=*%2CHubsExtension&flight=1&resourceMenuPerf=true#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Marketplace/GalleryFeaturedMenuItemBlade/selectedMenuItemId/home/searchQuery/Data%20Factory/resetMenuId/).
2. Click the `Copy Data` button as below to move to the `powercopytool` interface, and follow the tips to copy the folder step by step.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Took me a few tries to get this. Here is the key:

> If the specified source is a blob container or virtual directory, then
>   wildcards are not applied.

In other words, you can't wildcard copy files nested in a folder structure in a container. You have two options:

- Use /S WITHOUT a pattern to recursive copy everything
- Use /S and specify the full file path in your pattern without a wildcard

Example:

```
C:\Users\myuser>azcopy /Source:https://source.blob.core.windows.net/system /Dest:https://dest.blob.core.windows.net/system /SourceKey:abc /DestKey:xyz /S /V /Pattern:"Microsoft.Compute/Images/vmimage/myimage.vhd"
```

EDIT: Oops, my answer was worded incorrectly!

Answer (score -1):

Please specify the command without /S:

> AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1 /Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2 /SourceKey:key /DestKey:key /Pattern:abc.txt

You can find the information from "Copy single blob within Storage account" in http://aka.ms/azcopy .

Comment: I have read the "documentation" many times, it is not very helpful on patterns, especially folders and/or wildcards.  Also, as stated, I am not trying to copy a single blob, I am trying to copy a directory.

Comment: removing /S had no effect

Comment: Is your folder "CorruptZips/2013/6" under your blob container just like "container/CorruptZips/2013/6"? If so, this should work: /S /Pattern:CorruptZips/2013/6 . You can refer to "/Pattern:"file-pattern"" part in http://aka.ms/azcopy .

Comment: "If the specified source is a blob container or virtual directory, then wildcards are not applied. If option /S is specified, then AzCopy interprets the specified file pattern as a blob prefix. If option /S is not specified, then AzCopy matches the file pattern against exact blob names."